# Is there a way to make a div's height depend on one sub div's content but not another?

Tags: html, scroll, height, css

If I have a div with two sub div's within: is it possible to have height:auto; on the parent element but only apply it to one child element, and have the other set to overflow-y:scroll;?

Here is an examlpe: http://jsbin.com/equpor/2/edit

This is what I mean: can I make div.one adept it's height to div.two but ignore div.three?

Is there any proper way to solve this?
Thank you!

Edit: The content in div.three is generated by a php foreach loop from an xml file, so I want to be able to edit the xml without editing the html/css every time. So I don't know how long div.three will be. I want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. All you have to do is set a fixed height for div 3.

[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/MUZNs/3/)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that the content in div 3 is generated by a php foreach loop from an xml file, so I want to be able to edit the xml without editing the html/css every time. So I don't know how long div 3 will be. I want it to be dynamic.
My bad.